# Compute 3D angle given 2D vectors and their magnitude ratio

Tags: vector, graphics, computer-vision, data-science, angle

I have been trying to figure out whether the following problem has a solution. Almost having given up, I would like to ask whether someone can confirm that there is no solution, or maybe give me a hint.

- We have two vectors `v` and `w` in 3D space and know that the ratio of their magnitudes is `||v|| / ||w|| = 0.8019`.
- in 3D space an observer would see that they form an angle of `27.017` degrees.
- on the other side, an observer in 2D (only seeing the `x` and `z` axis), observes an angle of `7.125` degrees between the vectors.
- From their view, the vector coordinates are `v = (x: 2, z: 1)` and `w = (x: 3, z: 2)`.

**Is there somehow a way that the 2D observer can calculate the actual angle between these vectors in 3D space?**

I would be more than happy for any input. All my tries have failed so far and I just want to know whether there could be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem and get that the values of y1 and y2 are given by this function:

> eq1: 0.6439*y2^(2)-y1^(2)=9.785.

Therefore real angle can practically any value, the factor that would narrow this problem down to an actual solution would be the information about where the observer is in the 3d space so that he sees the angle of 27.017º, however, if this is the whole problem, then I can share my solution and process.

Some graphs that I created from my calculations:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! This is the whole problem yes, I would be more than glad to see your solution and discuss it further. Could you share your reasoning and steps? :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time :). What would you need to know about the observer's location? His distance to the origin?

Comment: The distance does not matter, however you would need to know his position relative to the origin, so technically another vector, then you could try to calculate the real angle, however I think that the problem would make more sense if you were given the task to find the coordinates of the two vectors given that the angle between vector1 and vector2 is something when looking straight down at the x and y axis of the graph and given the coordinates of x and y for both of the vectors as well as the ratio between their magnitudes.

Comment: The position of the observer relative to the origin would be exactly on the `y` axis, looking straight to the origin, from some unknown distance (the red line on your graph above). How could I find that the actual angle of the vectors is `27.017` degrees from that?

Answer (score 0):

The side view of the vectors is directly from the point of view of the x and z axis of the graph, therefore the coordinates of the (x1,z1) and (x2,z2) points(terminal points of the vectors), appear authentic, and not augmented, hence you can use them in your calculations to calculate the coordinates of z1 and z2, which you need to calculate the angle.

**V** = (x1, y1, z1)    **V** = (2, y1, 1)

**W** = (x2, y2, z2)    **W** = (3, y2, 2)

Since ||v|| / ||w|| = 0.8019

∴Then sqrt((x1^2)+(y1^2)+(z1^2))/sqrt((x2^2)+(y2^2)+(z2^2)) = 0.8019

∴(x1^2)+(y1^2)+(z1^2)/(x2^2)+(y2^2)+(z2^2) = 0.6430

∴4+(y1^2)+1/9+(y2^2)+4 = 0.6430

∴5+(y1^2) = 8.359 + 0.6430(y2^2)

∴13.359 = 0.6430(y2^2)-(y1^2)

This gives you therefore a function that calculates the other value of y given the some input y.

You can then graph this function using Geogebra.
[image]

For all the pairs of values on the curve, together with the fixed values of x and z for both of the vectors you can calculate that the ratio between the magnitudes of the two vectors is equal to 0.8019.

This problem has therefore infinitely many solutions for the angle as there are infinitely many values of z1 and z2 that satisfy the ratio; ||v|| / ||w|| = 0.8019.
Therefore the answer to this problem can be expressed as:

∀Θº∈R:Θº≥0